# Attendance Report in MySql

Tags: mysql, date, join, case

I want to write a query to generate attendance report of employee. First I will tell you how the presence of employee is stored in my database.

I have following tables.

```
Employee Table with Columns

    emp_id  emp_Name   Joining_Date
     1      john         11-01-2012
     2      Scott        12-01-2012


Holiday Table

Holiday_Name         Date 
Chrismas          25-12-2012  
Dushera           08-03-2012
Independance Day  15-08-2012

Leave Table

Subject  from_Date     to_Date      Emp_Id     status 
PL       02-01-2012    04-01-2012      1       Approved
CL       11-01-2012    12-01-2012      2       Declined      


Doctor Table

Subject   Call_Date    call_Done_By(emp_id)
 Call     15-01-2012      1
 CA       21-02-2012      2

Chemist Table
Subject   Call_Date    call_Done_By(emp_id)
Chemist   1-02-2012     2
Texo      21-03-2012    1
```

If employee is visited to doctor or chemist,that particular date is stored in that particular doctor or chemist table with employee_id

Now person will select year and month and he should be able to get attendance report in following format
Example : suppose user selects year as '2011' and month as 'Dec' then output should be

```
Employee   year  Month    1  2   3   4   5   6    7.... 
 John      2011   Nov     Y  Y   Y   Y   Y   L    S....
 Scott     2011   Nov     Y  Y   L   M   Y   L    S
```

here in output 1,2,3.... are days from 0-30 for a month which we can write using 'case'

Consider if employee is present on day show its status as 'Y' else L else
if he gone to any customer like doctor,chemist,then replace it with 'S'.

So how should I write a query to achieve this output??
any suggestions will be helpful for me....

Comment: is is still unclear ?let me know.

Comment: Your result set seems a but unclear. Is the 1 2 3 4 ect. column headings referring to day of the month? I see that you show only one letter as emp_name in your employee table but in the result set you show name. Could you add a example to the result set with the data you supplied?

Comment: yes sure , just check it, I have edited my question.. and yes column 1,2,3 refers days of months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a long way that should work as expected:

```
SELECT
    Employee.emp_Name,
    '2011' AS `Year`,
    'Dec' AS `Month`,
    CASE (
        IF(
            DATE('1-12-2011') < DATE(Employee.Joining_Date)),
            '0' --Not joined yet
            IF (
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Holiday WHERE DATE('1-12-2011') = DATE(Holiday.date)) = 1,
                '1', --National Holiday
                IF (
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Leave WHERE DATE('1-12-2011') > DATE(Leave.to_Date) AND DATE('1-12-2011') < DATE(Leave.from_Date) AND Leave.Emp_Id = Employee.emp_id) = 1,
                    '2', --On Leave
                    IF(
                        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Doctor WHERE DATE('1-12-2011') > DATE(Doctor.Call_Date) AND Doctor.call_Done_By = Employee.emp_id) = 1 OR 
                        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Chemist WHERE DATE('1-12-2011') > DATE(Chemist.Call_Date) AND Chemist.call_Done_By = Employee.emp_id) = 1,
                        '3' --Visit Doctor or Chemist
                        '4' --Employee was at work
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
        WHEN 0 THEN 'N/A' --Not joined yet
        WHEN 1 THEN 'L' --National Holiday
        WHEN 2 THEN 'L' --On Leave
        WHEN 3 THEN 'S' --Visit Doctor or Chemist
        ELSE 'Y' --Employee was at work
    END AS `1`, --first day of month
    ... AS `2`, --repeat for second day of the month till max day of current month replace '1-12-2011' with each different day of month
    ...
    ... AS `30`
FROM
    Employee
```

My suggestion is to create a view that does the if statement for each employee that way your code will be easier to maintain. Please keep in mind that this is pseudo code that might need some some changing to run.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes,I am trying to execute your logic,I will reply you in short time.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I really appreciate your effort. As you know if I have thousands of employee then according to your query we need to write 1000 views separately for each employee. As  each employee's joining date will be different.is it right? or am I considering in wrong way?

Comment: @PravinGate: You only write one view but you need to write it correctly. The view should have `emp_id, date(for each day after emp joined), value (determines if 0,1,2,3,4)` then you should be able to  `select sum(value) from view where emp_id = employee.emp_id and date = ('01-12-2011')` sum value to ensure one value, and since there is only one date entry per emp it should be the exact value.

Comment: Since you have to deal with the amount of days of the month and the view requires an entry for every day per employee after he joined I suggest you create a table that holds the days of the year (you will need to decide how to handle leap years). Then you can create the view by joining it with the date table creating an entry for each day of the year.