# Employee Whole Attendance Query

Tags: mysql, subquery, case

I am stucked with this problem from long time. Though you will find this is big question, but it's not............

I have following tables, with dummy data, so you can also try it.

```
     users Table with Columns

        emp_id  emp_Name  Joining_Date         state_id
          1       Lauren  11-07-2011           123         
          2       John    01-08-2012           234
          3       Smith   02-09-2011           234
____________________________________________________    
CREATE TABLE users 
( emp_id int
, emp_Name varchar(20)
, Joining_Date DATE 
, state_id int 
);

INSERT INTO users (emp_id, emp_Name, Joining_Date, state_id) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'John',  '2011-08-10', 123) ,
  (2, 'Smith', '2011-09-11', 234) ; 

__________________________________________________________________
       cl_doctor_call Table

        Subject Call_Date     call_Done_By(emp_id)
        Call       15-01-2012      1
        CA        21-02-2012       2
___________________________________________________________________     
CREATE TABLE cl_doctor_call 
( Subject  VARCHAR(10)
, Call_Date DATE
, call_Done_By INT 
) ;

INSERT INTO cl_doctor_call (Subject, Call_Date,call_Done_By) 
VALUES 
  ('sub1', '2011-08-15', 1) ,
  ('sub2', '2011-09-16', 2) ;
___________________________________________________________________

        cl_ chemist Table

        Subject       Call_Date     call_Done_By(emp_id)
        Chemist       1-02-2012              2
        Texo          21-03-2012             1

____________________________________________________________________________________
CREATE TABLE cl_chemist ( Subject  VARCHAR(10),  Call_Date DATE, call_Done_By INT   );

INSERT INTO cl_chemist (Subject, Call_Date,call_Done_By) VALUES ('sub3','2011-08-19',2),('sub5','2011-09-25',1);

___________________________________________________________
        cl_Stock Table

        Subject  Call_Date     call_Done_By(emp_id)
        Sub1     1-02-2012            1
        Sub2     21-03-2012           3
____________________________________________________________
CREATE TABLE cl_Stock 
( Subject  VARCHAR(10)
, Call_Date DATE
, call_Done_By INT
);

INSERT INTO cl_Stock (Subject, Call_Date,call_Done_By) 
VALUES 
  ('ABC',  '2011-10-13', 1) , 
  ('sub5', '2011-11-17', 2) ;

______________________________________________________    
        Meetings Table

        Subject Meeting_Date   call_Done_By(emp_id)
        Sub1     11-02-2012          1
        Sub2     23-03-2012          2    _____________________________________________________________________________________       
CREATE TABLE Meetings (   Subject  VARCHAR(10),   meet_Date DATE, meet_Done_By INT    );

INSERT INTO Meetings (Subject, meet_Date,meet_Done_By)
VALUES 
  ('Planning','2011-11-01',2),
  ('Deploy','2011-12-15',1);

______________________________________________________________________________________
        Leave Table
        Subject     from_Date         to_date       Requested_By(emp_id)   status
        Sub1        01-02-2012       03-02-2012           2               Declined
        Sub2       21-03-2012        22-03-2012           1               Approved

        Holiday Table

        Holiday_Name              Holiday_Date      States_Id
        New Year                  01-01-2012            123

       Independence Day          15-08-2012            234
______________________________________________________________________________________
CREATE TABLE Holiday (    Holiday_Name  VARCHAR(10),Holiday_Date DATE,   State_Id_c INT     );


INSERT INTO Holiday (Holiday_Name,Holiday_Date,State_Id_c) VALUES ('NEW_YEAR','2012-01-01',123), ('CHRISHMAS','2011-12-25',234);
______________________________________________________________________________________    
    Replace with date
    for stock='Y'
    for chemist='Y'
    for doctor='Y'
    for leave='L'
    for Sunday='S'
    for meeting ='M'
    for Holiday='H'

Hope so still you are with me.

 Now Admin will select 'month' and 'year' and according to that attendance report for 

 employee will displayed.

        Output :
        Employee     Year       Month     1 2 3 4 5 6 7.... for all 31 days
        John         2011       Nov       Y Y Y H Y L S....
        Smith        2011       Nov       Y Y Y H Y M S.....
          .           .          .        ................ 
          .           .          .        ................
        &so on      &so on     &so on     & so on
```

here in output 1,2,3.... are days from 0-31 for a month which we can write using 'case'

Consider if employee is present on day show its status as 'Y' ,if he is on leave show it's status as 'L; if there is Sunday show status 'S' for holiday show 'H' and so on.

So basically I want a write a query to retrieve all these details.

So pl z suggest me ways here, that How can I display this attendance Report by a query or procedure.

I have tried so far this .....

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `leosatyen_claris`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Test`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`leosatyen_claris`@`%` PROCEDURE `Test`(IN month_last_date DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT 
users.id AS Id,
users.first_name AS Employee,
CASE MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(main.cdate,'%d')='01' THEN main.task
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%W')='SUNDAY' THEN 0
              WHEN main.cdate IS NULL THEN -1
         ELSE -2 END)
     WHEN -1 THEN 'NA'
     WHEN  0 THEN 'S'
     WHEN  1 THEN 'Y'
     WHEN  2 THEN 'C'
     WHEN  3 THEN 'S1'
     WHEN  4 THEN 'P'
     WHEN  5 THEN 'M'

END Day1,
CASE MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(main.cdate,'%d')='02' THEN main.task
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY),'%W') ='SUNDAY' THEN 0
              WHEN main.cdate IS NULL THEN -1
         ELSE -2 END)
     WHEN -1 THEN 'NA'
     WHEN  0 THEN 'S'
      WHEN  1 THEN 'Y'
      WHEN  2 THEN 'C'
      WHEN  3 THEN 'S1'
      WHEN  4 THEN 'P'
      WHEN  5 THEN 'M'

END Day2,
.
.
. ## UP TO 31 DAYS

CASE MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(main.cdate,'%d')='31' THEN main.task
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 31 DAY),'%W')='SUNDAY' THEN 0
              WHEN main.cdate IS NULL THEN -1
         ELSE -2 END)
     WHEN -1 THEN 'NA'
     WHEN  0 THEN 'S'
     WHEN  1 THEN 'Y'
     WHEN  2 THEN 'C'
     WHEN  3 THEN 'S1'
     WHEN  4 THEN 'P'
     WHEN  5 THEN 'M'
END Day31 
FROM
users  
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cl_doctor_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')AS cdate,
  cl_doctor_call.created_by  AS emp,
  1     task     
  FROM 
  cl_doctor_call  
  WHERE 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_doctor_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')>month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_doctor_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_chemist_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d') AS  cdate,
  cl_chemist_call.created_by AS emp,
  2    task     
  FROM 
  cl_chemist_call
  WHERE 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_chemist_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')>month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_chemist_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_stockist_call_cstm.calldate_c,'%Y-%m-%d') AS cdate,
  cl_stockist_call.created_by AS emp,
  3         task
  FROM 
  cl_stockist_call LEFT JOIN cl_stockist_call_cstm
  ON cl_stockist_call.id=cl_stockist_call_cstm.id_c
  WHERE 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_stockist_call_cstm.calldate_c,'%Y-%m-%d')> month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_stockist_call_cstm.calldate_c,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cl_product_pramotional_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d') AS cdate,
  cl_product_pramotional_call.created_by AS emp,
  4       task
  FROM cl_product_pramotional_call
  WHERE  
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_product_pramotional_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')>month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_product_pramotional_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(meetings.date_start,'%Y-%m-%d') AS cdate,
  meetings.created_by AS emp,
  5        task
  FROM meetings
  WHERE  
  DATE_FORMAT(meetings.date_start,'%Y-%m-%d')> month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(meetings.date_start,'%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

 )AS main 
 ON main.emp = users.id 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(users.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')<= month_last_date
 GROUP BY users.id ;
 END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here I am getting all Sunday's of that month AND All customer calls like Doctor_call,
chemist call, stockist call and meetings  entries correctly.

Now I just need to add 'Leave' and Holiday Entries. So anybody can assist me to achieve holidays and leave in my existing procedure?

any suggestions will be helpful for me....

Comment: What have you tried? This looks the same as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158340/attendance-report-in-mysql)?

Comment: I have tried to create a stored procedure, in which i am passing a IN parameter which is previous month_last_date, as e.g :if you select November month it will take October-31-2011 as in parameter, from this I am able to calculate all Sundays in November month.oK. i will post my procedure here let see what we can do further.

Comment: I have posted my procedure that I tried so far.

Comment: Instead of suggestions you are down voting my post . I can understood, I am unable to solve this, but it's not an dump question.

Comment: When posting a question like this it is a good idea to include the CREATE TABLE statements and some INSERTS for dummy data so people who might help can quickly create a mock setup to work with.

Comment: I have added dummy data for my Tables. so it will be helpful to anyone to take try on it.

Comment: I am succeeded to get all customer calls and meeting entries in my report, now I just need to check for 'Leave' and 'Holiday' , can anybody assist me to achieve this?

Comment: Holiday is also working now, I 'll just need Leave, Can anybody tell me , what will be the select clause for leave as per this procedure format....  means I want leave clause like this way ... select (leave date between from date and to_date as 'cdate', cl_leave.created_by as emp from cl_leave...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved answer for Attendance Report.

We need to execute this lengthy stored procedure to get monthly attendance of all Employees.

To execute this procedure we need to pass IN parameter as last date of previous month like if we need to see December 2011 attendance Report pass '2011-11-30' AS IN parameter.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `Sample`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Test`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`Sample`@`%` PROCEDURE `Test`(IN month_last_date DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT 
users.id AS Id,DATE_FORMAT(month_last_date,'%Y')AS YEAR,DATE_FORMAT(month_last_date,'%M')AS MONTH,
CONCAT(users.first_name,users.last_name) AS Employee,cl_territories.name AS Territory,
CASE MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(main.cdate,'%d')='01' THEN main.task
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%W')='SUNDAY' THEN 0
              WHEN main.cdate IS NULL THEN -1
         ELSE -2 END)
     WHEN -1 THEN 'NA'
     WHEN  0 THEN 'S'
     WHEN  1 THEN 'Y'
     WHEN  2 THEN 'C'
     WHEN  3 THEN 'S1'
     WHEN  4 THEN 'P'
     WHEN  5 THEN 'M'
     WHEN  6 THEN 'H'
     WHEN  7 THEN 'L'
END Day1,
CASE MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(main.cdate,'%d')='02' THEN main.task
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY),'%W') ='SUNDAY' THEN 0
              WHEN main.cdate IS NULL THEN -1
         ELSE -2 END)
     WHEN -1 THEN 'NA'
     WHEN  0 THEN 'S'
      WHEN  1 THEN 'Y'
      WHEN  2 THEN 'C'
      WHEN  3 THEN 'S1'
      WHEN  4 THEN 'P'
      WHEN  5 THEN 'M'
      WHEN  6 THEN 'H'
      WHEN  7 THEN 'L'
END Day2,
.
.
. # upto 31 days

CASE MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(main.cdate,'%d')='31' THEN main.task
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 31 DAY),'%W')='SUNDAY' THEN 0
              WHEN main.cdate IS NULL THEN -1
         ELSE -2 END)
     WHEN -1 THEN 'NA'
     WHEN  0 THEN 'S'
     WHEN  1 THEN 'Y'
     WHEN  2 THEN 'C'
     WHEN  3 THEN 'S1'
     WHEN  4 THEN 'P'
     WHEN  5 THEN 'M'
     WHEN  6 THEN 'H'
     WHEN  7 THEN 'L'
END Day31
FROM
users  LEFT JOIN users_cstm
ON users.id=users_cstm.id_c
LEFT JOIN cl_territories
ON users_cstm.cl_territories_id1_c=cl_territories.id
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cl_doctor_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')AS cdate,
  cl_doctor_call.created_by  AS emp,
  1     task     
  FROM 
  cl_doctor_call  
  WHERE 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_doctor_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')>month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_doctor_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_chemist_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d') AS  cdate,
  cl_chemist_call.created_by AS emp,
  2    task     
  FROM 
  cl_chemist_call
  WHERE 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_chemist_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')>month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_chemist_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_stockist_call_cstm.calldate_c,'%Y-%m-%d') AS cdate,
  cl_stockist_call.created_by AS emp,
  3         task
  FROM 
  cl_stockist_call LEFT JOIN cl_stockist_call_cstm
  ON cl_stockist_call.id=cl_stockist_call_cstm.id_c
  WHERE 
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_stockist_call_cstm.calldate_c,'%Y-%m-%d')> month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_stockist_call_cstm.calldate_c,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cl_product_pramotional_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d') AS cdate,
  cl_product_pramotional_call.created_by AS emp,
  4       task
  FROM cl_product_pramotional_call
  WHERE  
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_product_pramotional_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')>month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(cl_product_pramotional_call.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(meetings.date_start,'%Y-%m-%d') AS cdate,
  meetings.created_by AS emp,
  5        task
  FROM meetings
  WHERE  
  DATE_FORMAT(meetings.date_start,'%Y-%m-%d')> month_last_date AND
  DATE_FORMAT(meetings.date_start,'%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cl_holidays_structures.holiday_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS cdate,
users.id AS emp,
6    task
FROM users LEFT JOIN users_cstm
ON users.id=users_cstm.id_c
LEFT JOIN cl_states
ON users_cstm.cl_states_id1_c=cl_states.id
LEFT JOIN cl_holidays_structures
ON cl_holidays_structures.cl_states_id_c=users_cstm.cl_states_id1_c
WHERE  
DATE_FORMAT(cl_holidays_structures.holiday_date,'%Y-%m-%d')> month_last_date AND
DATE_FORMAT(cl_holidays_structures.holiday_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
UNION ALL
SELECT cl_leave_management_cstm.from_date_c+ INTERVAL td.days DAY cdate, 
users.id AS emp,
7    task
FROM
  cl_leave_management LEFT JOIN cl_leave_management_cstm
  ON cl_leave_management.id=cl_leave_management_cstm.id_c
LEFT JOIN users 
  ON cl_leave_management.created_by = users.id
JOIN temp_days td
  ON DATEDIFF(cl_leave_management_cstm.to_date_c, cl_leave_management_cstm.from_date_c) >= td.days
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(cl_leave_management_cstm.from_date_c,'%Y-%m-%d')> month_last_date AND
 DATE_FORMAT(cl_leave_management_cstm.from_date_c,'%Y-%m-%d')<=DATE_ADD(month_last_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND
 cl_leave_management_cstm.status_c='Approved'

 )AS main 
 ON main.emp = users.id 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(users.date_entered,'%Y-%m-%d')<= month_last_date
 GROUP BY users.id ;
 END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks to all who guide me to get this result.